# if i use jquery datepicker with year selection enabled, how to make that form selection work with chosen.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-chosen

it's hard to pick year when it's a long list, i want to combine chosen.js

any idea ?

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('.chosen').chosen();
    }
});

$('.selector').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        $('.chosen').chosen();
    }
});
```

above code i've tried. not working.

Comment: is it shows any error in console?

Comment: nothing, but now i use bind a focus event after .datapicker(); it's working, but when i click that inputbox it happens two times. any better way to do that ?

Comment: on what ? you mean .on not .bind

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ instead of bind try with .on()